# Remove SRC tag and replace it without requerying the server

Tags: html, image, src

my html looks like this :

```
<article>
<img src="http://mydomain.com/image.jpg"> 
</article>
```

when the article is not in view, I remove the img tag from the article, , and when its in view I insert the img in the article, now the problem is that everytime I do that, a new query to the server is made, the client redownloads the image.

is there a solution to this ? i"ve seen some websites remove images et reset them without any queries back to the server :/

Comment: `img.style.display = "none"` or like @LauriElias said.

Comment: I wan tto remove completely the tag from the DOM, because I am generating a very big list. :/

Comment: So, let me get this straight...You don't want to redownload the images, meaning you want to keep them in a client-side cache or in memory, but you think keeping the few bytes of DOM-data is too much?

Comment: the images are cached anyway, and since the Add/remove to dom occures really fast because it depends on the scrolling, I dont want the user to spam my server with image requests everytime he scrolls. this is too much for my small server

Comment: ok the problem wasnt with the img tag, it was how I retrieved the images, since I dont use an img name in my URL everytime i set the img tag, the browser doesnt look for it in the cache.
basically, I have to put a nae.extension to all my images, or else the browser queries the server...thats weird :/

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: What is the code you have now? What are the cache settings on the image resources? And what is the practical reason why you cannot just hide the `img` elements with CSS? Or have them in an element that gets inserted into the document and removed from it, still existing as an element.